# Skip step if file input resource does not exist

Tags: spring-batch

I have 12 Steps in a single job in which steps are reading from csv and txt files. I'm trying to add the functionality of skipping the step if the file corresponding to the step doesn't exist in the directory using JobExecutionDecider following this https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#programmaticFlowDecisions. It'is working fine when the files are not present in the directory. Instead if the files are present it stops at the first from.

```
jobBuilderFactory.get("importFileJob")
            .listener( new ImportFileJobListener() )
            .incrementer( new RunIdIncrementer() )
            .start( truncateAnagraficheTableStep( QUERY_TRUNCATE_INTERFACE_IN_ANAGRAFICHE ) )
            .next( new Decider( directory, file01Prefix ) ).on( "FAILED" ).to( truncateContrattiTableStep( QUERY_TRUNCATE_INTERFACE_IN_CONTRATTI ) )
            .from( new Decider( directory, file01Prefix ) ).on( "COMPLETED" ).to( anagraficheStep( QUERY_INSERT_INTERFACE_IN_ANAGRAFICHE ) )
            .next( anagraficheStep( QUERY_INSERT_INTERFACE_IN_ANAGRAFICHE ) )
            .next( truncateContrattiTableStep( QUERY_TRUNCATE_INTERFACE_IN_CONTRATTI ) )
            .next( new Decider( directory, file02Prefix ) ).on( "FAILED" ).to( truncateCapitalLimitTableStep( QUERY_TRUNCATE_INTERFACE_IN_CAPITAL_LIMIT ) )
            .from( new Decider( directory, file02Prefix ) ).on( "COMPLETED" ).to( contrattiStep( QUERY_INSERT_INTERFACE_IN_CONTRATTI ) )
            .next( contrattiStep( QUERY_INSERT_INTERFACE_IN_CONTRATTI ) )
            .next( truncateCapitalLimitTableStep( QUERY_TRUNCATE_INTERFACE_IN_CAPITAL_LIMIT ))
            .next( new Decider( directory, file03Prefix ) ).on( "FAILED" ).to( truncateEsitiPefTableStep( QUERY_TRUNCATE_INTERFACE_IN_ESITI_PEF ) )
            .from( new Decider( directory, file03Prefix ) ).on( "COMPLETED" ).to( capitalLimitStep( QUERY_INSERT_INTERFACE_IN_CAPITAL_LIMIT ) )
            .next( capitalLimitStep( QUERY_INSERT_INTERFACE_IN_CAPITAL_LIMIT ))
            .next( moveTextFilesStep() )
            .next( truncateEsitiPefTableStep( QUERY_TRUNCATE_INTERFACE_IN_ESITI_PEF ) )
            .next( new Decider( directory, file04Prefix ) ).on( "FAILED" ).to( truncateStatoOperazioniTableStep( QUERY_TRUNCATE_INTERFACE_IN_STATO_OPERAZIONI ) )
            .from( new Decider( directory, file04Prefix ) ).on( "COMPLETED" ).to( esitiPefStep() )
            .next(esitiPefStep())
            .next( truncateStatoOperazioniTableStep( QUERY_TRUNCATE_INTERFACE_IN_STATO_OPERAZIONI ) )
            .next( new Decider( directory, file05Prefix ) ).on( "FAILED" ).fail()
            .from( new Decider( directory, file05Prefix ) ).on( "COMPLETED" ).to( statoOperazioniStep() )
            .next( statoOperazioniStep() )
            .next( moveExcelFilesStep() )
            .end()
            .build();
```

Here is the code of the decider

```
public class Decider implements JobExecutionDecider {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("techLog");
private File directory;
private String filePrefix;


public Decider(File directory, String filePrefix) {
    super();
    this.directory = directory;
    this.filePrefix = filePrefix;
}


@Override
public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String status;
    
    File[] inputFiles = directory.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.startsWith(filePrefix) );
    if ( inputFiles.length == 0 ) {
        logger.error( "Input resource does not exist file " + directory + "\\" + filePrefix );
        status = "FAILED";
    }
    else {
        status = "COMPLETED";
    }
    return new FlowExecutionStatus(status);
}
```

}

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-batch-conditional-flow

Comment: From tomorrow I'm trying to figure this out but in vain.
Tried after first start     
.on("COMPLETED").to(new Decider( directory, file01Prefix ) )
But still not going to the next step

Answer (score 0):

That's an issue with your decider implementation. It is up to you to specify the `FlowExecutionStatus` to return according to the presence/absence of the file.

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud, I have updated the question adding the code of the decider. I believe that I am doing something wrong in the implementation of the job flow.

Comment: `It'is working fine when the files are not present in the directory. Instead if the files are present it stops at the first from.`: That's because you are returning `COMPLETED`. You can use custom statuses (like "FILE_ABSENT", "FILE_PRESENT", etc) and use those in your flow definition: `on("FILE_ABSENT")...`. Using "FAILED"/"COMPLETED" are not good choices for your case IMO (do you consider an absence of a file as a failure?).

Comment: Thank You for the explanation.
do you consider an absence of a file as a failure?
Actually I've to create logs if the file is not present and to avoid the exceptions if the strict mode is true and the file is not present.

Comment: At the moment the procedure is that the first decider checks the first file if present it moves to step reading the file otherwise moves to the second decider to check the second file and so on.
There could be a better way to implement this kind of procedure.